# Convert Table to JSON

Tags: json, xpath, yahoo-pipes

I am still taking baby steps with Yahoo Pipes and struggling with what I believe should be a simple task.

I have a [table on a page](http://hydrotel.water.nsw.gov.au/210.html) that is being updated in realtime (every 1-2 minutes).
I want to extract the rows, push into a Pipe, and then spit out a JSON in the following format:

```
"sites": [
 {
      "Site": "210001-Singleton",
      "LastSampleTime": "29/04/2014 11:51:00",
      "RiverLevel": "0.744",
      "FlowRate": "501.6",
      "FlowRate": "0.744",
      "Rainfall": "",
      "WaterTemp": "",
      "Conductivity": ""
  },
etc.
```

I think I am right in thinking that once I have pulled the relative table components with an XPath fetcher, I would make use of a Loop with an Item Builder contained within it to spit out the data into the above format.  However, I am struggling with trying to pull in the simple table.

Here is a simplified version of [my yahoo pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=e586fd190c3ef6370d121f909d5cd62f).
I have tried multiple variations of the XPath string to try and get just the rows I need.
From inspecting the table with firebug, I know that the TRs I want, all seem to share the same height of `tr style="height:18px"`
However, not sure if this is the best way to extract them.

Can someone assist in providing some pointers on how to pull the table into my desired format?  Not too sure where I am going wrong with Xpath

Comment: The link to your pipe doesn't work anymore, it seems you deleted the pipe. If you put it back I can try to have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Import.io can do what you want. Even though the HTML on that site is a bit messy, you can still use a custom xpath override within the tool.

I built the first row of data for you, so all you need to do is go in and edit the existing extractor adding in more columns using the following extractor as a start point https://import.io/data/set/?mode=loadSource&source=f867a123-091e-4596-bbea-871df2d5ceb7

Just open it up, edit the extractor and add the cols you need. Here is the xPath code I used:

```
    /html/body/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[5]
```

Row 7 in the table is the first row with data, and td[2] is the first cell in. Just increase the number in the tr[x] to hit the next row.

Once you have the data structured, hit integrate, and follow the instructions. Use the import.io support to help too, thats what they are there for.

*If the table will be expanded with more rows, you may want to change the xPath to work off of the values of the child element of the tr*

Disclaimer: I work at import.io, other tools exist.